# The convergence of the integral of square of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Recently, I came across the convergence for the integral of Brownian motions in continuous time case.

How to prove the following almost sure convergence?
 \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{B_{T}\int_{0}^{T}B_{t}dt}{T\int_{0}^{T}(B_{t})^{2}dt}
&\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow }&0\,,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $B$ is a Brownian motion and  $\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow }$ denote
convergence almost surely.

I'm thinking this is really obvious, But I cannot get my head round it. I thought about using the iterated logarithm for Brownian motion ($\limsup_{t\to \infty}\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{2t\log\log(t)}}=1$).

I will deal with $\int_{0}^{1}(B_{u})^{2}du$ as follows:

1) Since $\Bbb E\left[\exp(-u\int_0^t B^2_s\,ds)\right]={1\over\sqrt{\cosh(t\sqrt{2u})}}.$

2) We can see that
 \begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t {B_s}^2 ds\right] &=&\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \int_0^t B_s dB_s\right)^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \frac{1}{2} B_t^2-\frac{1}{2}t\right)^2\right]\\
&=&\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{4} B_t^4+\frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{2}B_t^2t\right]=
\frac{3}{4}t^2+\frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{2}t^2=\frac{t^2}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{Var}\left[ \int_0^t {B_s}^2 ds\right] &=& \mathbb{E}\left[\left( \int_0^t {B_s}^2 ds\right)^2\right] - \left(\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t {B_s}^2 ds\right]\right)^2\\
&=&\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \int_0^t {B_s}^2 ds\right)^2\right] - \frac{t^4}{4}=\frac{1}{36}\mathbb{E}\left[\left(B_t^4-4\int_0^t B_t^3dB_t\right)^2\right]-\frac{t^4}{4}\,.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, using the scaling properties, for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have
 \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{B_{T}\int_{0}^{T}B_{t}dt}{T\int_{0}^{T}(B_{t})^{2}dt}&\overset{d}{=}&
\frac{T^{\frac{3}{2}}B_{T}\int_{0}^{1}B_{u}du}{{T}^{3}%
\int_{0}^{1}(B_{u})^{2}du}=\frac{B_{T}\int_{0}^{1}B_{u}du}{T^{\frac{3}{2}}
\int_{0}^{1}(B_{u})^{2}du}\leq \frac{T^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon}\int_{0}^{1}B_{u}du}{T^{\frac{3}{2}}
\int_{0}^{1}(B_{u})^{2}du}\\
&=&\frac{T^{\varepsilon}\mathbb{N}(0,1)}{T
\int_{0}^{1}(B_{u})^{2}du}=\frac{T^{\varepsilon}O_{p}(1)}{T
\int_{0}^{1}(B_{u})^{2}du}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow }0\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\overset{d}{=}$ denotes equivalence in distribution and $\mathbb{N}$ denotes Normal distribution.

Is my derivation is correct?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assume for now that with probability 1,
$$\limsup_{T\to \infty}\frac 1 T \int_0^T \mathbf 1[|B_t|\leq 2] dt < \frac 1 3.\tag{*}$$

Assuming (*), for all sufficiently large $T$,
$$\frac 1 T\int_0^T (B_t^2-|B_t|)dt \geq \frac 2 3\cdot 2+\frac 1 3\cdot \left(-\frac 1 4\right)\geq 0$$

which implies $\int_0^T B_t^2 dt \geq |\int_0^T B_t dt|.$ You know that $B_T/T$ tends to $0$ almost surely, which gives the claimed convergence
 \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{B_{T}\int_{0}^{T}B_{t}dt}{T\int_{0}^{T}(B_{t})^{2}dt}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0.
\end{eqnarray*}

It remains to show that (*) holds with probability $1$. This should be a complete no-brainer, but I don't know the right reference. Here are two arguments:

**Proof 1:** Consider the embedded continuous-time random walk on $\mathbb Z$ obtained by defining $\tau_0$ to be the maximum value $\tau_0\leq t$ such that $B_{\tau_0}$ is an integer, then letting $S_t=B_{\tau_0}$. The process $S_t$ is a continuous-time (and "non-exploding") Markov chain so its transition probabilities converge, and by the shift symmetry of $\mathbb Z$ they must converge to $0$. This means the time spent in $\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$ up to time $T$ is eventually at most $T/4$. If you prefer positive recurrent Markov chains, take $S_t$ modulo $100$.

**Proof 2:** Define variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$ by
$$X_n=\frac 1 {t_0} \int_{(n-1)t_0}^{nt_0} \mathbf 1[|B_t|\leq 2]dt.$$

where $t_0$ is chosen large enough such that $\mathbf E[X_n|B_{(n-1)t_0}]<1/10$ regardless of $B_{(n-1)t_0}$ - this is possible by the absolute continuity of Brownian motion occupation measure (see Mörters and Peres's *Brownian Motion*, Theorem 3.25) and by the scaling property of Brownian motion. We can choose variables $Y_n$, depending only on $B_{(n-1)t_0}$, to get $\mathbf E[X_n+Y_n|B_{(n-1)t_0}]=1/10$. Then by the martingale strong law of large numbers applied to the sequence $X_n+Y_n$,
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {nt_0} \int_0^{nt_0} \mathbf 1[|B_t|\leq 2] dt < 1/10$$
with probability $1$. Comparing to the left-hand-side of (*) with $n=\lfloor T/t_0\rfloor$, the difference is bounded by $t_0/T$ which is less than $1/3-1/10$ for $T\geq 10t_0$ say.

Comment: Can I use the the scaling properties to prove the convergence? Thanks for your help. How to deal with $\frac{B_{T}^{2}}{\int_{0}^{T}(B_{t})^{2}dt}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow }0$.

Comment: @steven: if you have another question could you add it to the original post? I don't see how scaling property arguments would be enough by themselves.